# regex replace string path in quotes

Tags: powershell, regexp-replace

hello  i have a config file with end like this on many server so i need to add # in the begin of the line

"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\McAfee\DesktopProtection\UpdateLog.txt"  8h   warning    *   0800    1800

"C:\EURNTCC\mcafee\sucessfull-update.log.txt"         8h   warning    *   0800    1800

i made a little script like this

```
$file="\\server\C$\osit\etc\act_mon.cfg"

$text1='"C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\ALL USERS\APPLICATION DATA\MCAFEE\DESKTOPPROTECTION\UPDATELOG.TXT"'

$text2='"C:\EURNTCC\MCAFEE\SUCESSFULL-UPDATE.LOG.TXT"'

 (gc $file) -replace $text2 ,("#" + $text1) |Set-Content $file
 (gc $file) -replace $text2 ,("#" + $text2) |Set-Content $file
```

i have this error any help to understand this error , i have 650 server to update

The regular expression pattern "C:\EURNTCC\MCAFEE\SUCESSFULL-UPDATE.LOG.TXT" is not valid.
At line:1 char:1

- (gc $file) -replace $text1 ,("#" + $text1) |Set-Content $file
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ("C:\EURNTCC\MCA...UPDATE.LOG.TXT":String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-replace` uses Regex. The strings you want it to search for have characters that have special meaning in regex that need to be prefixed with a backslash. (most notably the dots and backslashes)

You don't have to do this manually but you can use the static method `Escape()` from the `[regex]` type accelerator:

```
$text1 = '"C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\ALL USERS\APPLICATION DATA\MCAFEE\DESKTOPPROTECTION\UPDATELOG.TXT"'
$text2 = '"C:\EURNTCC\MCAFEE\SUCESSFULL-UPDATE.LOG.TXT"'

$search1 = [regex]::Escape($text1)
$search2 = [regex]::Escape($text2)
```

Also, you can chain `replace` so you don't have to get the content twice:

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace $search1 ,("#" + $text1) -replace $search2 ,("#" + $text2) | Set-Content $file
```